# How do I specify that a struct field must implement a trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a trait `Foo`

```
pub trait Foo {
   fn do_something(&self) -> f64;
}
```

and a struct which references that trait

```
pub struct Bar {
   foo: Foo,
}
```

Trying to compile I get

```
error: reference to trait `Foo` where a type is expected; try `Box<Foo>` or `&Foo`
```

Changing the struct to

```
struct Bar {
   foo: &Foo,
}
```

Tells me `error: missing lifetime specifier`

Changing the definition to

```
struct Bar {
   foo: Box<Foo>,
}
```

Compiles — yay!

However, when I want a function to return `foo` on `bar` - something like:

```
impl Bar {
    fn get_foo(&self) -> Foo {
        self.foo
    }
}
```

Well obviously `bar.foo` is a `Box<Foo>`, so expectedly I get `` error: reference to trait `Foo` where a type is expected; try `Box<Foo>` or `&Foo` ``

Changing the signature to

```
impl Bar {
    fn get_foo(&self) -> Box<Foo> {
        let this = *self;
        this.foo
    }
}
```

But now I get `` error: cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer `` on trying to dereference `self`.

Changing to

```
impl Bar {
    fn get_foo(self) -> Box<Foo> {
        self.foo
    }
}
```

Is all good.

So....

1. Why doesn't `&` in the `bar` struct work? I'm assuming I have to box
   as structs have a set memory layout so we have to say it's a pointer
   to a trait (as we can't know how big that will be), but why does the
   compiler suggest something that wont compile?
2. Why can't I dereference `self` in `get_foo()` - All examples I've seen use the borrowed `self` syntax?
3. What's the implication of removing the `&` and just using `self`?

Learning Rust is fascinating, but the memory safety is both fascinating and intimidating!

Code in full that compiles:

```
trait Foo {
    fn do_something(&self) -> f64;
}

struct Bar {
    foo: Box<Foo>,
}

impl Bar {
    fn get_foo(self) -> Box<Foo> {
        let foo = self.foo;
        foo.do_something();
        foo
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Answer (score 174, accepted):

This is the tricky point of trait objects, you need to be very explicit about who owns the underlying object.

Indeed, when you use a trait as a type, the underlying object must be stored somewhere, as trait objects are in fact references to an object implementing the given trait. This is why you cannot have a bare `MyTrait` as a type, it must be either a reference `&MyTrait` or a box `Box<MyTrait>`.

### With references

The first method you tried was was with a reference and the compiler complained about a missing lifetime specifier :

```rust
struct Bar {
   foo : &Foo,
}
```

The problem is, a reference doesn't own the underlying object, and an other object or scope must own it somewhere: you are only borrowing it. And thus, the compiler need information about how long this reference will be valid: if the underlying object was destroyed, your Bar instance would have a reference to freed memory, which is forbidden !

The idea here is to add lifetimes:

```rust
struct Bar<'a> {
   foo : &'a (Foo + 'a),
}
```

What you are saying here to the compiler is : "My Bar object cannot outlive the Foo reference inside it". You have to specify the lifetime two times : once for the lifetime of the reference, and once for the trait object itself, because traits can be implemented for references, and if the underlying object is a reference, you must specify its lifetime as well.

On special case would be writing:

```rust
struct Bar<'a> {
   foo : &'a (Foo + 'static),
}
```

In this case, the `'static` requires that the underlying object must be a real struct, or a `&'static` reference, but other references won't be allowed.

Also, to build your object, you will have to give it a reference to an other object you store yourself.

You end up with something like this :

```rust
trait Foo {}

struct MyFoo;

impl Foo for MyFoo {}

struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a (Foo + 'a),
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn new(the_foo: &'a Foo) -> Bar<'a> {
        Bar { foo: the_foo }
    }

    fn get_foo(&'a self) -> &'a Foo {
        self.foo
    }
}

fn main() {
    let myfoo = MyFoo;
    let mybar = Bar::new(&myfoo as &Foo);
}
```

### With Boxes

A Box contrarily owns its content, thus it allows you to give ownership of the underlying object to your Bar struct. Yet, as this underlying object could be a reference, you need to specify a lifetime as well :

```rust
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: Box<Foo + 'a>
}
```

If your know that the underlying object cannot be a reference, you can also write:

```rust
struct Bar {
    foo: Box<Foo + 'static>
}
```

and the lifetime problem disappears completely.

The construction of the object is thus similar, but simpler as you don't need to store the underlying object yourself, it is handled by the box :

```rust
trait Foo {}

struct MyFoo;

impl Foo for MyFoo {}

struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: Box<Foo + 'a>,
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn new(the_foo: Box<Foo + 'a>) -> Bar<'a> {
        Bar { foo: the_foo }
    }

    fn get_foo(&'a self) -> &'a Foo {
        &*self.foo
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mybar = Bar::new(box MyFoo as Box<Foo>);
}
```

In this case, the `'static` version would be :

```rust
trait Foo {}

struct MyFoo;

impl Foo for MyFoo {}

struct Bar {
    foo: Box<Foo + 'static>,
}

impl Bar {
    fn new(the_foo: Box<Foo + 'static>) -> Bar {
        Bar { foo: the_foo }
    }

    fn get_foo<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Foo {
        &*self.foo
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mybar = Bar::new(box MyFoo as Box<Foo>);
    let x = mybar.get_foo();
}
```

### With the bare value

To answer your last question :

> Whats the implication of removing the & and just using self?

If a method has a definition like this :

```rust
fn unwrap(self) {}
```

It means it will consume your object in the process, and after calling `bar.unwrap()`, you won't be able to use `bar` any longer.

It is a process used generally to give back ownership of the data your struct owned. You'll meet a lot of `unwrap()` functions in the standard library.

Comment: WOW. Thanks for so much detail. I'm going to read this through a few times before accepting, but it gives me so much to play with and try to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description! - This is a steep learning curve coming from a background in class-based languages.

Comment: It seems that the lifetime restrictions have changed since then. I can now write `foo: &'a Foo` and `foo: Box<Foo>`. What explains these changes?

Answer (score 24):

To note for future reference: the syntax has changed from

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo + 'a,
}
```

to

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a (Foo + 'a), // with parens
}
```

Per [RFC 438](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/438)

Comment: I think this is outdated *again* :) Now you also need to fiddle in some `dyn`, so my compiler tells me.

Answer (score 15):

With the 2021 edition, `dyn` is now a [requirement](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/05/11/edition-2021.html#promoting-two-warnings-to-hard-errors) for the Trait objects. The `box` syntax is still unstable as of 1.57, so should use `Box::new()` instead (but there is no need to cast it). So I think the above example by @Levans should be modified a bit. Note that lifetimes are no longer needed either.

```rust
trait Foo {}

struct MyFoo;

impl Foo for MyFoo {}

struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: Box<dyn Foo + 'a>,
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn new(the_foo: Box<dyn Foo + 'a>) -> Bar<'a> {
        Bar { foo: the_foo }
    }

    fn get_foo(&'a self) -> &'a dyn Foo {
        &*self.foo
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mybar = Bar::new(Box::new(MyFoo));
}
```

Comment: It is no longer necessary to include the lifetime annotations either as rustc can imply their existence for this example.

Comment: Be careful though, omitting the lifetime does mean something different than providing them explicitly. Here `Box<dyn Foo>` is inferred to be `Box<dyn Foo + 'static>`.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize that. I will revert it for now

Comment: Do you think you could edit the existing answer instead with this updated information?