# Explicit lifetime declarations in trait objects held by structs

Tags: rust, lifetime

In the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212397/rust-lang-references-to-traits-in-structs) there's a discussion of how to refer to trait objects held by structs which requires the following syntax:

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a (Foo + 'a),
}
```

This is per [RFC 438](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0438-precedence-of-plus.md)

Could I ask for more explanation of the double lifetime declaration? Levans said:

> You have to specify the lifetime two times : once for the lifetime of
>   the reference, and once for the trait object itself, because traits
>   can be implemented for references, and if the underlying object is a
>   reference, you must specify its lifetime as well.

I understand the notion of a lifetime for the reference in the struct. But I don't understand why the lifetime isn't for the object that the trait is a trait on. Put another way, I don't know what it means to hold a reference for a trait without holding a reference to the underlying thing that it's a trait for.

Is there a case where the trait and the underlying object would have different lifetimes? What would it mean to hold onto a reference to a trait without holding on to the underlying thing the trait is on?

Asking yet another way, why can't Rust just do The Right Thing(tm) with:

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo,
}
```

where The Right Thing(tm) would be to interpret that as equivalent to the declaration above?

Sorry to bombard with questions, but I felt like I was doing something pretty basic (use a trait as a generic facet), and I had to go down the rabbit hole pretty deep, and I'd like to understand why the rabbit hole is that deep.

The error message: `error: explicit lifetime bound required` was decidedly unhelpful, because there is a lifetime bound already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> why the lifetime isn't for the object that the trait is a trait on

Because the reference to the trait object and the trait object itself might have different lifetimes. Here's an example of a trait that is implemented for a reference:

```
trait Quack {
    fn quack(&self) { println!("Quack") }
}

impl<'a> Quack for &'a bool {}

struct MasterQuack<'a> {
    q: &'a (Quack + 'a),
}

fn main() {
    let a = true;
    // a.quack(); // Nope, not defined
    (&a).quack();

    // MasterQuack {q: &a}; // Nope, this would be a reference to a boolean, which isn't Quack
    MasterQuack {q: &&a};
}
```

One thing to note is that it's perfectly fine to have `&'a (Trait + 'b)` - that is, a reference to a trait that itself has a / is a reference, and those lifetimes are different. You said as much with

> Is there a case where the trait and the underlying object would have different lifetimes?

But it's more a case of "the underlying object has references with different lifetimes".

> why can't Rust just do The Right Thing(tm)

As of [RFC 599](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/1f5d3a9512ba08390a2226aa71a5fe9e277954fb/text/0599-default-object-bound.md) this now compiles:

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo,
}
```

Comment: related: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0141-lifetime-elision.md#lifetime-elision-in-structs