# How does borrowing Box<Trait> contents work?

Tags: rust, traits, borrow-checker

I have [this minimal example code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0c5143e47f61c4c717a227ca6ffc5a49&version=stable&backtrace=0):

```
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;

trait Foo {}
struct Bar;
impl Foo for Bar {}

fn main() {
    let mut encryptor: Box<Foo> = Box::new(Bar);

    encrypt(encryptor.borrow_mut());
}

fn encrypt(encryptor: &mut Foo) { }
```

but it fails with this error:

```
error: `encryptor` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:11:1
   |
10 |     encrypt(encryptor.borrow_mut());
   |             --------- borrow occurs here
11 | }
   | ^ `encryptor` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

The kind people at #rustbeginners found that I have to dereference the box to get the contents, and then borrow the contents. [Like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7ca3e1df15274b780a3cea80cb186a26&version=stable&backtrace=0):

```
trait Foo {}
struct Bar;
impl Foo for Bar {}

fn main() {
    let mut encryptor: Box<Foo> = Box::new(Bar);

    encrypt(&mut *encryptor);
}

fn encrypt(encryptor: &mut Foo) { }
```

---

It works, but I don't understand it.

Why do I need to dereference first? What is the error trying to say? Normally it isn't an error that a value is dropped at the end of the function.

---

Apparently it's not just me who doesn't understand how this works; an [issue has been filed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38624).

Comment: Note that you don't even need to call `encrypt` to get this error; just attempting to create a standalone mutable reference via `borrow_mut` would fail.

Comment: A [code version of ljedrz's comment](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=c36fba752d8b9500d3b1356c4f33dcd1&version=stable).

Comment: There is some discussion at https://users.rust-lang.org/t/trait-objects-and-borrowmut/8520

Answer (score 10):

Let's start with a change that allows the code to work:

```
fn encrypt(encryptor: &mut (Foo + 'static)) { }
```

The important difference is the addition of `+ 'static` to the trait object - the parens are just needed for precedence.

The important thing to recognize is that there [are *two* lifetimes present in `&Foo`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27790168/155423):

- a lifetime for the reference itself: `&'a Foo`
- a lifetime that represents all the references inside the concrete value that the trait abstracts: `&(Foo + 'b)`.

If I'm reading the RFCs correctly, this was introduced by [RFC 192](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/1f5d3a9512ba08390a2226aa71a5fe9e277954fb/text/0192-bounds-on-object-and-generic-types.md), and [RFC 599](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/1f5d3a9512ba08390a2226aa71a5fe9e277954fb/text/0599-default-object-bound.md) specified reasonable defaults for the lifetimes. In this case, the lifetimes *should* expand like:

```
fn encrypt(encryptor: &mut Foo) { }
fn encrypt<'a>(encryptor: &'a mut (Foo + 'a)) { }
```

On the other end of the pipe, we have a `Box<Foo>`. Expanded by the rules of the RFC, this becomes `Box<Foo + 'static>`. When we take a borrow of it, and try to pass it to the function, we have an equation to solve:

- The lifetime inside the trait object is `'static`.
- The function takes a reference to a trait object.
- The lifetime of the reference equals the lifetime of references inside the trait object.
- Therefore, the reference to the trait object must be `'static`. Uh oh!

The `Box` will be dropped at the end of the block so it certainly isn't static.

The fix with explicit lifetimes allows the lifetime of the reference *to* the trait object to differ from the lifetime of the references *inside* the trait object.

If you needed to support a trait object with internal references, an alternate is to do something like:

```
fn encrypt<'a>(encryptor: &mut (Foo + 'a)) { }
```

---

True credit for this explanation [goes to nikomatsakis and his comment on GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38624#issuecomment-273332870), I just expanded it a bit.